# CORS issue in calling userInfo from google API in react

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I am using `@react-oauth/google` with Implicit method of getting user info from google account.
This is the code I use

```
const handleGoogleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: async (tokenResponse) => {
      console.log(tokenResponse);
      const token = pathOr('', ['access_token'], tokenResponse)
      const userInfo = await axios.get(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
        { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": window.location.origin } },
      );

      console.log("user",userInfo);
    },
    onError: errorResponse => console.log(errorResponse),
  });
```

In the axios request, I get the following error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo' from origin 'https://mywebsite:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Can anyone help fix this cors issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used XMLHttpRequest and it's working without any cors error.

```
const userInfo = await new Promise(resolve => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) 
          resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
         else resolve({ err: '404' });
        };
        xhr.send();
      });
```